# Selenium with Python: can't select inside <!DOCTYPE ... Transitional//EN>

Tags: python, selenium, select, xpath

I am new to Python and Selenium and trying to web scrape a page with electoral data (https://historico.servel.cl/SitioHistorico/index2008_alca.htm, html code in picture below). On this page I need to navigate using Selenium since the url doesn't change while selecting items in the menu. As a first step I need to select the "División Geografica" button in the top left corner. I tried to navigate to the corresponding tag using `find_element_by_xpath()`.

However, navigating by xpath only works for tags outside the `#document` and  `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">` lines. As an example, `driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/frameset[1]/frame")` gets me to the first  tage just before `#document`, but I am unable to select any of the `<body>`, `<form>' or` tags that come after. I also tried selecting elements using the name of a tag, e.g. `driver.find_element_by_name("DATOS")`, but without success. Is this because of the `' and/or '#document' tags/lines or what is the issue here?

The object I am interested in is `<a href="geografico.htm" .... </a>`. Do you have any suggestions how I can select it using xpath (or any other method)?

Thanks a lot for your help!
best,
likeat.100

[source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rU0FJ.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This element `<a href="geografico.htm" .... </a>` is in a **frame**. You need to switch the focus/control of your webdriver to interact with it.

for switching the control of WebDriver you can use this code :

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_name('guiaFrame'))
```

then you can easily interact with the mentioned web element.

Remember it is always a good practice if you switch back the focus of WebDriver to it's parent/default once you are done with the current frame , for that you have to use :

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

HTH !!